# How to you get AVAudioEnvironmentNode.listenerPosition to update?

Tags: swift, arkit, avaudioengine

I am trying to use an AVAudioEnvironmentNode() with AVAudioEngine and ARKit.

I am not using ARSCNView or any of the other ARViews, this is just a plain ARSession.

I have a sound source -> AVAudioEnvironmentNode -> AVAudioEngine.mainOut.

I understand how set the position of the sound source. I am trying to figure out how to move the audioListener.  Because I want to walk around the sound source in space.

The Apple Documentation says that to update the node's listener position you use.

```
AVAudioEnvironmentNode.listenerPosition = AVAudio3DPoint(newX, newY, newZ)
```

When I pass the ARCamera's forward and up to the node, that seems to change fine.  However when I trying to change the position, I do not hear anything, and when I print a debug of listenerPosition, the output stays at zero origin, even those the camera's position is moving.

Is there something I have to do to make the AVAudioEnvironmentNode movable to take a new position?

Thanks.